# Bandwidth and Carrier frequency

Tags: frequency, bandwidth

What is exactly the difference between the Bandwidth and the carrier frequency ?
And if we have two channels with the same bandwidth but with different carrier frequency will we have different speeds ? 
For example :

- System A :
  Bandwidth = 1 Khz , 
  Carrier frequency = 1 Ghz
- System B :
  Bandwidth = 1 Khz , 
  Carrier frequency = 1 Mhz

If we used 16-QAM in both systems will baudrate be the same ?

Comment: Do you understand the answer to this question: [Why is channel capacity a factor of bandwidth instead of frequency?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86151/6334)

Comment: Actually I couldn't understand this part " A single frequency signal would be a continuous tone. It's amplitude would never change. It would just continue on repetitively forever. As such, it would not convey any information."

Comment: I mean why would it continue repetitively ? If so wouldn't we be able to transmit data over it changing phase like in PSK ?

Comment: What is the fourier transform of \$\sin(\omega t)\$? If you change the phase then you have \$\sin(\omega t + m(t))\$. If you take the F.T. of this, you won't get the same as for the simple sine, you'll get something spread over a band of frequencies. Put another way: once you modulate the phase, you no longer have a single-frequency signal.

Comment: So the answer to the question  is yes and speed stay the same ?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather say if you do QAM-16 with the same baud rate, then the required bandwidth is the same whether the carrier is 1 MHz or 1 GHz.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to research more further to understand it well. could you suggest any resources or videos that explain frequencies bands and this subject ?